# String comparison not working in PowerShell function - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: windows, git, shell, powershell, scripting

I'm trying to make an alias of `git commit` which also logs the message into a separate text file. However, if `git commit` returns `"nothing to commit (working directory clean)"`, it should NOT log anything to the separate file.

Here's my code. The `git commit` alias works; the output to file works. However, it logs the message no matter what gets returned out of `git commit`.

```
function git-commit-and-log($msg)
{
    $q = git commit -a -m $msg
    $q
    if ($q –notcontains "nothing to commit") {
        $msg | Out-File w:\log.txt -Append
    }
}

Set-Alias -Name gcomm -Value git-commit-and-log
```

I'm using PowerShell 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$q` contains a string array of each line of Git's stdout. To use `-notcontains` you'll need to match the full string of a item in the array,  for example:

```
$q -notcontains "nothing to commit, working directory clean"
```

If you want to test for a partial string match try the `-match` operator. (Note - it uses regular expressions and returns a the string that matched.)

```
$q -match "nothing to commit"
```

`-match` will work if the left operand is an array. So you could use this logic:

```
if (-not ($q -match "nothing to commit")) {
    "there was something to commit.."
}
```

Yet another option is to use the `-like`/`-notlike` operators. These accept wildcards and do not use regular expressions. The array item that matches (or doesn't match) will be returned. So you could also use this logic:

```
if (-not ($q -like "nothing to commit*")) {
    "there was something to commit.."
}
```

Comment: "$q contains a string array of each line of git's stdout." Only if git produces more than one line of output. If git only outputs one line to stdout, then $q will contain a single string, not an array (something I noted in my answer).

Comment: Multiple lines are returned from the OPs git commit commit (tried it on my machine).

Comment: I don't use that tool so I can't comment on that. But I just wanted to point out that this specific answer can't be generalized to all cases of capturing a command-line tool's output.

Comment: Bill, the `-match` and `-like` operators will work whether the left operand is a single string or an array. If the left operand is an array, the items that matched will be returned and which may be used in a boolean test expression (non-empty result will be translated to true). If the left operand is a single string, a boolean will be directly returned.

Comment: Agreed, you can use this kind of logic if you're aware of the potential implications.

Comment: I do appreciate the extra information on how the stdout thing works, though. Thanks, gentlemen. :)

Answer (score 4):

Just a note that the **-notcontains** operator doesn't mean "string doesn't contain a substring." It means "collection/array doesn't contain an item." If the "git commit" command returns a single string, you might try something like this:

```
if ( -not $q.Contains("nothing to commit") )
```

I.e., use the **Contains** method of the String object, which does return $true if a string contains a substring.

Comment: `$q` contains a string array (all lines from git's stdout)... so `$q.Contains("nothing to commit")` won't work, `$q[1].Contains("...")` would however.

Comment: I already noted that when I said "if the 'git commit' command returns a single string".